# How to store the content of a JTextArea into a class?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm working on a program that serves as a hypothetical email system in which users can be created and can send messages to other users that have been created.

The message will be stored in a "Message" class, and the text is typed in a JTextArea in a GUI.  What I want to know is how I would go about storing the text typed into the JTextArea, in the exact same layout (indentations and all), within the Message class.  I thought about text files but then there would have to be one for each message, potentially creating an infinite number of them, and I don't like the concept of having to make a system for coming up with unique names for each text file.

Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `getText` or am I missing something in the question

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that made me chuckle and shake my head. Totally missed that myself

Comment: `"I thought about text files but then there would have to be one for each message, potentially creating an infinite number of them"` -- Why try to re-invent the wheel? This sort of issue has been answered long ago by the experts -- use a database.

Comment: I believe `JComponent` implements `Serializable`, why don't you check if serialization could work? @MadProgrammer I think the issue is that the OP wants to save other properties of the `JTextArea` in addition to text, such as formatting.

Comment: @ostrichofevil `JTextArea` doesn't have formatting, it's a plain text editor - `Serializable` will serialize the `JTextArea` object itself, I'm not entirely sure that's what the OP's after either

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm well then serialization would probably work, as the text is in one of the object's fields, but it would totally be overkill.

Comment: @ostrichofevil So, just use `getText` - that will return the text in the same format that it appears in the `JTextArea` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply implement the [`DocumentListener` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html), then do the following:

```
JTextArea someMessage = new JTextArea();
someMessage.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
someMessage.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Area");
```

Here, we assume the name of the listener you implement is called `MyDocumentListener`, and the implementation could be as simple as:

```
class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
    String newline = "\n";
 
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateLog(e, "inserted into");
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateLog(e, "removed from");
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //Plain text components do not fire these events
    }

    public void updateLog(DocumentEvent e, String action) {
        Document doc = (Document)e.getDocument();
        int changeLength = e.getLength();
        displayArea.append(
            changeLength + " character" +
            ((changeLength == 1) ? " " : "s ") +
            action + doc.getProperty("name") + "." + newline +
            "  Text length = " + doc.getLength() + newline);
    }
}
```

Examples taken from [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html). I recommend reading the rest of that article as it goes into much depth of how to effectively listen for updates to the internal document model.

#### How to get text that was inserted

[`insertUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html#insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent)) is what notifies you when ***new*** text has been typed into the textarea. You can get the freshly inserted text by calling off to the [`DocumentEvent#getOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html#getOffset()) and [`DocumentEvent#getLength`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html#getLength()). Using both methods, you can get the offset (index) within document where the insertion happened, as well as the length of the change.
Then to get the actual text that was inserted, you call [`DocumentEvent#getDocument#getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#getText(int,%20int)) and supplying the offset and length you got from the event.

#### How to get all the text in the textarea

You can use this similar method to get the entire text in the document by making use of [`Document#getStartPosition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#getStartPosition()) and [`Document#getEndPosition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#getEndPosition()), then calling [`Document#getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#getText(int,%20int)).

Or even easier, [`JTextArea#getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText())

Comment: That's great but where I'm confused is how getDocument() would work.  Like, how am I storing the content interpreted by the MyDocumentListener()?

Comment: @PCRevolt `getDocument` returns the internal document model of the textarea. This is the data structure that keeps track of the text within the textarea

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that this all seems to be stored in a JTextArea.  But I am wanting to store the content in a class I create called Message.  I suppose I could store a JTextArea in each instance of Message, but I noticed that getDocument() returns a Document (which I've never heard of until now).  Is there some way to add a document to a JTextArea?  I'm trying to determine how I can copy the content of the Document to a different JTextArea.

Comment: @PCRevolt, I just described one of the ways. Read those links and you will well on your way to keeping track of every change within the Textarea

Comment: @PCRevolt, if you are not bound to using swing, I will recommend Javafx, as this kind of issue is simply a matter of doing `myCustomData.textProperty().bind(myTextarea.textProperty())` in JavaFx. JavaFx is very different from swing programming, so only switch if you are not time constrained